# jQuery - Combine variables and strings inside .css() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you combine strings and variables as properties in the `.css()` method in jQuery?

I can easily do it if setting `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` but they aren't supported in Firefox & Opera.

```
function bgPos() {
    jq('element').each(function() {
        var bgPosX = 10;
        var bgPosY = 20;
        jq(this).css("background-position", "bgPosX + 'px', bgPosY + 'px'");
    });
}
```

Comment: remove the quotes around your variable names.
jq(this).css("background-position", bgPosX + 'px', bgPosY + 'px');

Comment: Agh! I should have tried it without the quotes, I don't know why I stuck to the idea that the whole statement has to be wrapped in quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The other answers here are incorrect as jQuery's `css()` method does not support 3 parameters and they will cause your `bgPosY` value to be ignored completely (and defaulted to `50%`).** I'm not actually sure how one of them received multiple upvotes...

---

You have two options here:

### String Concatenation

You can concatenate your two variables into one string by using the `+` symbol:

```
.css({ backgroundPosition: bgPosX + "px " + byPosY + "px" })
```

Note how I've removed the comma between `px` and `bgPosY` and added a space to separate the two: `"px "`.

### Setting Individual Properties

Alternatively you can just set the individual `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` properties:

(**Edit:** as Blazemonger has pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385110/jquery-combine-variables-and-strings-inside-css-method/25385372?noredirect=1#comment39590063_25385372), these individual properties aren't supported in Firefox, so if you wish to support Firefox you should use the first option instead).

```
.css({
    backgroundPositionX: bgPosX,
    backgroundPositionY: bgPosY
})
```

---

*Worth noting that I'm using object notation here rather than using strings, simply because I find this to be neater. You can stick to using `"background-position"` for the first example, and use `"background-position-x"` and `"background-position-y"` for the second example if you'd prefer.*

Comment: The first approach is more universal; Firefox doesn't (currently) support the individual X and Y properties.

Comment: @Blazemonger ah you're quite correct. I wasn't aware that wasn't supported in Firefox.

Comment: It should be, IMO, but that's Mozilla for you -- standards-compliant to a fault.

Answer (score 2):

`.css` doesn't accept 3 argument, so you can achieve what you want by giving an object.

say like bellow

```
jq(this).css({ backgroundPosition: bgPosX + "px " + byPosY + "px" });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was upvoted twice. It's wrong. jQuery's `css()` method does not accept 3 arguments like you've done here.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, sorry because I just focused on the problem which was given there.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I don't see 3 arguments but 1 passed here.

Comment: @Bart you can view the edit history here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25385184/revisions

Comment: @Bart sorry he was right, I updated my answer, if you will see the edits you will find.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ok sorry.

Comment: @Mritunjay jQuery's `css()` method accepts one or two arguments. Please refer to jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/. You've now just copied what I put in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the quotes around the variable:

```
jq(this).css("background-position", bgPosX + 'px' + bgPosY + 'px');
```

And get rid of the second comma...